# Добавление класса при определенных условиях

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать. Есть Шапка и меню внутри шапки, при разрешении экрана > 992 и скролле экрана, например на 30 пикселей вниз, то добавлять класс к меню и убирать этот же класс если вернулись в начало страницы(в самый верх), а при разрешении экрана < 992 и том же скролле добавлять класс к шапке и также его убирать если вернулись в начало страницы.

Внизу примерный код(нерабочий), того что пытаюсь сделать.

```js
$(window).resize(function () {
 if ($(window).width() > 992 && $(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
  $('.header__nav').addClass('js-fixed');
 } else {
  $('.header__nav').removeClass('js-fixed')
 }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
 if ($(window).width() < 992 && $(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
  $('.header').addClass('js-fixed');
 } else {
  $('.header').removeClass('js-fixed')
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Зачем 2 раза `window resize`?

Comment: И еще вы говорите что добавлять класс и при `>992` и `<992`? Один и тот же класс да?

Comment: @StackOverflow Да, один и тот же класс, вообще я просто скопировал первый `window resize`, для понятности второго условия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 992 && $(window).scrollTop() > 30){
    $('.header__nav').addClass('js-fixed');
    $('.header').removeClass('js-fixed');
  }
  else if($(window).width() < 992 && $(window).scrollTop() > 30){
    $('.header').addClass('js-fixed');
    $('.header__nav').removeClass('js-fixed');
  }
  else{
    $('.header__nav').removeClass('js-fixed');
    $('.header').removeClass('js-fixed');
  }
});
```

Первый кусок работает при `window resize`.

А это будет работать при событии `window scroll`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 992 && $(window).scrollTop() > 30){
      $('.header__nav').addClass('js-fixed');
      $('.header').removeClass('js-fixed');
    }
    else if($(window).width() < 992 && $(window).scrollTop() > 30){
      $('.header').addClass('js-fixed');
      $('.header__nav').removeClass('js-fixed');
    }
    else{
      $('.header__nav').removeClass('js-fixed');
      $('.header').removeClass('js-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Добавляется один тот же класс, но при >992, он добавляется к `.header__nav`, а при <992, к `.header`

Comment: @МихаилЗахаров Вот так уже наверное то что вы хотели.

Comment: Прочтите, пожалуйста , условия наверху. Всё работает, но только не при скролле. Т.е класс добавляется если страница изначально во время загрузки было опущена на `30px`, не представляю как это сделать и условие `else` попросту не срабатывает ;d

Comment: Огромное спасибо)